# Need help minimizing the Kullback-Leibler divergence between discrete observations and a complicated distribution.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

TL;DR: I want to fit the probability distribution $P(x) = \int_{0}^{x} N_0(z) \hspace{0.1cm} dz \int_{x}^{W} N_1(z) \hspace{0.1cm} dz$ to a bunch of discrete observations in order to obtain $N_0$ and $N_1$ which produced them. I fail at solving the following equations and need help at how to approach this:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \mu_1} \sum_{z=0}^{x} O(x)\hspace{0.1cm} ln \left(\int_{0}^{x} \frac{1}{\sigma_1 \sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{(x-\mu_1)^2}{2\sigma_1^2}} dz \right), \hspace{0.5cm}\frac{\partial}{\partial \sigma_1} \sum_{z=0}^{x} O(x)\hspace{0.1cm} ln \left(\int_{0}^{x} \frac{1}{\sigma_1 \sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{(x-\mu_1)^2}{2\sigma_1^2}} dz \right)$$

---

My motivation comes from this paper:
[Probabilistic Object Detection: Definition and Evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com).

The authors define a probability distribution over all pixels $(u', v')$ of an image as a product of integrals of two 2D-Gaussian distributions $N_0$ and $N_1$, which represent bounding box corners. The exact formula is:
$$P(u', v') = \int \int_{0, 0}^{u', v'} N_0(u, v) \hspace{0.1cm} du \hspace{0.1cm} dv \int \int_{u', v'}^{H, W} N_1(u, v) \hspace{0.1cm} du \hspace{0.1cm} dv$$

where $H$ and $W$ are width and height of the image.

This procedure allows one to get from two bounding-box gaussians to a probability distribution over all pixels - however, I wanted to solve the opposite problem of trying to reconstruct the two gaussians given the pixel-wise probability distribution.

To do that, I first want to solve a simpler, 1D version of this problem. Here is an image showing the 1D problem: [Visualization of the 1D problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aT658.png)

In a 1D setting, the element-wise probability distribution simplifies to this calculation:
$$P(x) = \int_{0}^{x} N_0(z) \hspace{0.1cm} dz \int_{x}^{W} N_1(z) \hspace{0.1cm} dz$$

In this example there are 16 discrete probability valuse at each of 16 positions of the 1D array. In my toy example I just made up two gaussians to calculate the resulting $P(x)$. The "observations" are discretizations of that $P$ with some gaussian noise added.

My approach to reverse engineer the two gaussians from the observations was to minimize the Kullback-Leibler divergence between observations and the combined integrated distribution. This leads to my problem: After some reformulation of the KL-divergence I'm stuck at actually minimizing it, because the logarithm doesn't act directly on the gaussians but on the integrals. I don't know how to approach the problem from here, or if an analytical solution even exists at all.

I'll write down the steps I have done so far. $W$ is the width of the 1D array and $O(x)$ the observation at position x:

$$D_{KL} (O||P) = \sum_{x=1}^W O(x) ln \left(  \frac{O(x)}{\int_{0}^{x} N_0(z) \hspace{0.1cm} dz \int_{x}^{W} N_1(z) \hspace{0.1cm} dz} \right)$$
$$= \sum_{x=1}^W O(x) \left[ln (O(x) - ln \left( \int_{0}^{x} N_0(z) \hspace{0.1cm} dz \right) - ln \left( \int_{x}^{W} N_1(z) \hspace{0.1cm} dz \right)\right]$$
$$= \sum_{x=1}^W O(x) ln(O(x) - \sum_{x=1}^W O(x)\hspace{0.1cm} ln \left( \int_{0}^{x} N_0(z) \hspace{0.1cm} dz \right)- \sum_{x=1}^W O(x)\hspace{0.1cm} ln \left( \int_{x}^{W} N_1(z) \hspace{0.1cm} dz \right)$$

If I want to minimize this term, that brings me to the following subproblem (each of the optimization variables $\mu_1, \mu_2, \sigma_1, \sigma_2$ is only in one of the terms, so for each only one of the addends is relevant):

$$max \hspace{0.1cm} \mu_1,\sigma_1 \sum_{z=0}^{x} O(x)\hspace{0.1cm} ln \left(\int_{0}^{x} \frac{1}{\sigma_1 \sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{(x-\mu_1)^2}{2\sigma_1^2}} dz \right) \rightarrow$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \mu_1} \sum_{z=0}^{x} O(x)\hspace{0.1cm} ln \left(\int_{0}^{x} \frac{1}{\sigma_1 \sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{(x-\mu_1)^2}{2\sigma_1^2}} dz \right)$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \sigma_1} \sum_{z=0}^{x} O(x)\hspace{0.1cm} ln \left(\int_{0}^{x} \frac{1}{\sigma_1 \sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{(x-\mu_1)^2}{2\sigma_1^2}} dz \right)$$

This is the point at which I don't really know what to do anymore. If anybody can point me at how to solve this or a completely different approach to get to the two original gaussians without iterative numeric approaches, I'd be really thankful!